# React native redux update fields using api

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I have two files, one a child component Calculator.js and a parent component App.js that I am trying to connect together using react native redux.

The child component looks like this:

```
class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
  this.getApi();
    return (
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.fieldTitles}>Rate Calculator</Text>
        <View style={styles.field}>
            <Text>Mode of{"\n"}Payment</Text>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1', marginBottom: 10 }}>
            <Picker
                selectedValue={this.props.modeOfPayment}
                style={{ height: 50, width: 200}}
                onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.props.changeModeOfPayment(itemValue)}>
                <Picker.Item label="Monthly" value="monthly-payment" />
                <Picker.Item label="Annual" value="annual-payment" />
            </Picker>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.field}>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyle}>Coverage</Text>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyleAmount}>{this.props.coverage}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.field}>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyle}>Face Amount</Text>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyleAmount}>{this.props.faceAmount}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.field}>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyle}>Premiums</Text>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyleAmount}>{this.props.premiums}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.field}>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyle}>Total Premium</Text>
            <Text style={styles.calculatorStyleAmount}>{this.props.totalPremium}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        modeOfPayment: state.modeOfPayment,
        coverage: state.coverage,
        faceAmount: state.faceAmount,
        premiums: state.premiums,
        totalPremium: state.totalPremium,
        firstName: state.firstName,
        lastName: state.lastName,
        DOB: state.DOB,
        ageNearest: state.ageNearest,
        gender: state.gender,
        smoker: state.smoker,
        advisorName: state.advisorName,
        advisorPhoneNumber: state.advisorPhoneNumber,
        advisorEmail: state.advisorEmail
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getApi: () => dispatch({ type: 'GET_API' }),
        changeModeOfPayment: (itemValue) => dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_MODE_OF_PAYMENT', payload: itemValue})
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calculator)
```

and the parent component has redux components:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_MODE_OF_PAYMENT':
            return {...state, modeOfPayment: action.payload}
        case 'GET_API':
            quotePromise.then((quote) => {
            return {...state, totalPremiums: quote.totalPremiums.annualPremiumsCents}
            }
            );
    }
    return state
}

const store = createStore(reducer)
```

My goal is to call to an api and update the this.props.coverage/faceAmount/premiums text fields in the child component. My api code looks like this:

```
const getQuote = () => {
  return fetch('https://staging.testcompany.ca/quotes', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": 'b3242e0c9-43-461a-341-23',
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "ageNearest": 63,
      "gender": "FEMALE",
      "smokerStatus": "SMOKER",
      "plan": "DEFERRED_ELITE_TERM",
      "term": "LEVEL_TEN",
      "faceAmount": 50000
    })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};

const quotePromise = getQuote();
quotePromise.then((quote) => {
  console.log(`Quote retrieved. Total annual premiums: $${quote.totalPremiums.annualPremiumsCents / 100}`)
}
);
```

When calling the API, the body values will be changing according to the current states. How can I implement it so that the the text values change and re-render every time the body values change and the api is recalled? Would I place the api call code within the parent component or the child component? In the above example, I tried calling this.getApi() in the child component before it renders to trigger the switch to get the values of the promise but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you should never have asynchronous code in your reducer. I would suggest creating an `actions` folder to store your actions in, move your `getQuote` logic there and dispatch the result from that to your reducer. The asynchronous code in your reducer is probably why this isn't working